# Clearing cache for key value

Tags: caching

Folks, a quick one - I'm caching fields e.g: `$data` from nodes using the following:

```
cache_set("nids:$nid", $data, 'my_custom_cache');
```

I have a cron set up to clear all cached data from this bin using the following:

```
cache_clear_all('nids', 'my_custom_cache', TRUE);
```

But, if I want to clear only one particular cached node, how would I achieve this?  Currently tried:

```
cache_clear_all('nids:'.$nw->getIdentifier(), 'my_custom_cache', TRUE);
```

But no luck, how do can I specify this?

Comment: That last line looks right, except you don't want a wildcard match if you're trying to match on the exact id

Comment: `cache_clear_all('nids:'.$nw->getIdentifier(), 'cache_pwc_gant');` - this was it, cheers!